# How to get type inference of a nested object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to get type inference of dynamics objects. I searched through the site but didn't find exactly what i was looking for. I am sorry if it is repeated.

Basically I want to have some global constants objects of the same shape, so that I switch which is active but still being able to have the same properties inside, but only with different values.

```js
const example = {
    constant1: {
        value1: 'value1',
        value2: 'value2',
        value3: 'value3',
    },
    constant2: {
        value1: 'other value1',
        value2: 'other value2',
        value3: 'other value3',
    },
    constant3: {
        value1: 'another value1',
        value2: 'another value2',
        value3: 'another value3',
    },
};
```

So the example object can have any property, but they have to be equal, if I change one of the values inside one of the constants, I need it to throw an type error, but if I change in everyone of them, it's fine.

This is how I tried at first, it seemed to work but not how i would like it.

```js
interface TypeTest<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}

const CreateTest = <T>(obj: TypeTest<T>) => obj;

const test = CreateTest({
    some: {
        other: 'test',
    },
    thing: {
        other: 'testing',
    },
});

type constants = keyof typeof test;
```

As interfaces don't get type inference, I am using a creator function that receives the object and returns it typed. But it don't type the inner objects, as typescript infer a union type of each inner object. Also I don't get any type of the outer object, as
`type constants = string | number`

To work around this, I tried it this way:

```js
type TypeTest<D, T> = {
    [key in keyof D]: T;
};

const CreateTest = <D, T>(obj: TypeTest<D, T>) => obj;

const test = CreateTest({
    some: {
        other: 'test',
    },
    thing: {
        other: 'testing',
    },
});

type constants = keyof typeof test;
```

Now I get the right type of the outer object(`type constants = "some" | "thing"`), but completely lost type inference of the inner object, as now I only the unknown type, even if if I use `[key2 in keyof T]: string` as the shape of the inner object, it still is unknown.

I was able to work around all this, but in the end the developer experience is not that great.

```js
interface TypeTest<T extends readonly string[], U extends readonly string[]> {
    outer: T;
    inner: U;
    values: {
        [Property1 in T[number]]: {
            [Property2 in U[number]]: string;
        };
    };
}

const CreateTest
= <
    T extends readonly string[],
    U extends readonly string[],
> (constants: TypeTest<T, U>) => constants.values;

const test = CreateTest({
    outer: [ 'some', 'thing' ] as const,
    inner: [ 'other' ] as const,
    values: {
        some: {
            other: 'test',
        },
        thing: {
            other: 'testing',
        },
    },
});

type constants = keyof typeof test;
type values = keyof typeof test[constants];
```

Now I pass two arrays that are only used to get the types and thrown away after, also both arrays have to be asserted as const, otherwise I only get `string[]` type out of them.

So, is there a way to pass an object to the `CreateTest()` function, and get the typed value out of it? With
`type constants = "some" | "thing"`
and
`type values = "other`

EDIT:

The level of nesting is only 2 levels deep. But is it possible to get more of it?

Also is it possible to get different level of nesting? Like one object having 3 levels of nesting while other having 5.

I won't be needing it that way, I am just curious.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WY4YQm) meet your needs?  Please test against your use cases.  If it works for you I can write up an answer explaining it.  If not, please [edit] the question to demonstrate a failed use case.

Comment: @jcalz thank you so much. It worked great for me. It is exactly what I want. If you could explain how it works, I would appreciate.

Comment: Okay I will do so when I get a chance, probably sometime in the next 12 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to write a `createTest()` helper function which takes a single parameter `obj`, of a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `T` where we [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` to an object type in which all the properties are the same type, and specifically the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the properties from `T`.

When you tried to constrain all properties to the same type, the compiler inferred a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the properties.  This is often desirable, since it is as permissive as possible; a value of type `{a: A, b: B}` will always be assignable to the type `{a: A | B, b: A | B}`.  But you only want to accept things where `A` and `B` already agree with each other.  By switching the constraint to `{a: A & B, b: A & B}` it will enforce that.

Anyway, we can implement this as a [recursive constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification)

```
const createTest = <T extends IntersectProps<T>>(obj: T) => obj;
```

where `IntersectProps<T>` is defined as

```
type IntersectProps<T> =
  { [K in keyof T]: (x: T[K]) => void }[keyof T] extends
  (x: infer I) => void ? Record<keyof T, I> : never;
```

It works similarly to the union-to-intersection code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50374908/2887218); we walk through each property, put it in a contravariant position, and then infer from it.  The other question explains it more.  But you can see for yourself that this type does intersect properties:

```
interface A { x: 1 };
interface B { y: 2 };
type Example = IntersectProps<{ a: A, b: B }>;
/* type Example = {
    a: A & B;
    b: A & B;
} */
```

Okay, so let's try it:

```
const badTest = createTest({
  a: { b: 1, c: "", d: true },
  // ------> ~ <--- error
  e: { b: 2, c: 3, d: false }
  // ------> ~ <--- error
})
```

That fails because the intersection type `{b: number, c: string, d: boolean} & {b: number, c: number, d: boolean}` is equivalent to `{b: number, c: never, d: boolean}`, and the `c` property in each of the `a` and `e` properties cannot be assigned to `never`.  You can fix it by changing one of the `c` properties to be the same type as the other:

```
const goodTest = createTest({
  a: { b: 1, c: "", d: true },
  e: { b: 2, c: "z", d: false }
}) // okay
```

So now you can get the behavior you want without adding redundant information in the arguments to `createTest()`:

```
const test = createTest({
  some: {
    other: 'test',
  },
  thing: {
    other: "okay",
  },
});

type Constants = keyof typeof test;
// type Constants = "some" | "thing"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRAVR0YF4YB50ZEAPNMAEwhgEkw14JFgoAFeEABwkID5eAFCABGAKwBcMdAEpcvGCNEBuAFAqoAT06Ja9RI2ZsO3PrhUwYAbxgBtANIwAlmBgBrRBpAAzKQF1JAiSS6Pa+sjjyAG4gjhQwAL427p4+6L7EZIiUEOYwgZLOXvq04VExcQD8MABKzCDwFPjJ3lIANLTykmCIkfqqKs4MXsjAOgCCVjBBMACMCaqD+sOjMABCkxqSAEzz6lo6AKIkyAC2nAA2Onh0DEws7Fw81siSY+3CkuvxvKoA9ABUME02hgR1OFyuVlyFheMAmADI1qoLBYPnCYIjVqp4jB-r81CpQJBYMJkBRMNg8AgUGgKVABJZcrDrGiZu1gJIAESc9oUSRQeAAVx08VauV+vxgAFoZbL5AA-Aiy4jwDjwXKISQs7bsyQAZl5kmG5yYCXFktlcpgivwyv0apU8WkBKJ2AA5iAQOSsLAqUhUBgfQymVqYKzdTBuYagUKRWKLJrJmithHOQAvHkwPkwY2m+KO51qV2wNCUuD+2lBxkWCAgE6J6sokBQAAW+kkAHJS1AO-GEn3W843VroQpW+3IyBXMgNDzcqKC-1gToAMLgaDIejUPDNHzLlrdv6S5cwNfEzdQbeR2v1zkwAA+kcHYDdnKAA)